# SwiftUI Italic text clipping

Tags: ios, swiftui

I noticed that a `Text` with `.italic()` clips letters:
[image]

Setting frame size doesn't help:
[image]

`.paddings()` doesn't help either. `kerning(5)` I don't want to use as it fixes the problem partially, at the right edge only, but it adds unwanted letter spacing.

```
struct ItalicTest: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("F")
        .font(Font.system(size: 60))
        .italic()
        .fontWeight(.black)
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

I'd like to prevent clipping. Do you know a solution using pure `SwiftUI`?

Comment: Put a space on both ends of your string?  `Text(" F ")`

Comment: Sure I can do this. But it's sort of dirty hack, I'd like to find The Truth, maybe there is some setting I miss.

Comment: I agree, adding spaces is sort of a dirty hack, which is why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: That seems to be unexpected behaviour, so I suspect it is a bug worth reporting to Apple in Feedback.

Comment: Just submitted a report. But I wonder, the same behaviour I observe in UILabel, seems this bug persisted for years.

Comment: Any resolution from Apple or anyone? Is this an issue with the font itself maybe?

Comment: This issue appears to be fixed in Xcode 15, iOS 17. 

There are also new view modifiers to help the Text component render the text correctly, but for English and my use case it's not needed https://developer.apple.com/documentation/updates/swiftui#Text-input-and-output

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but I just had the same issue and found a propper solution.

You will have to add padding to your text and ask swiftui to collapse the padding and text before rendering it.

```
struct ItalicTest: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("F")
        .font(Font.system(size: 60))
        .italic()
        .fontWeight(.black)
        .padding(.horizontal) // <-- add padding
        .drawingGroup() // collapse the view and render together
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. somehow it doesn't work for me  Did you try it on iOS 15?

Comment: It doesn't work with foregroundStyle

Comment: Works fine on iOS15, please add a minimum viable example of what doesn't work.

Comment: For iOS 16 adding .foregroundStyle (except Color type) will solve the problem and you no need to use .drawingGroup, e.g.
foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [color], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
but on the same time for iOS 15 .foregroundStyle with LinearGradient won't work with .drawingGroup.

Comment: Interest find, but behaves inconsistently. Sometimes crashes if certain modifiers are out of order. Also I get a yellow box with red slash when trying to use the font in text fields.

Comment: I ended up using this workout since it works fine for most cases but can lead to issues in certain languages e.g Swedish rendering 'Å'. Instead of top right corner or bottom left, tall characters are clipped. The issue appears to be fixed in Xcode 15 iOS 17.